# Custom ES6 JavaScript Error issue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

After refactoring custom errors for ES6 in a large public library ([pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)), I'm getting some strange reports that the custom errors may not instantiate correctly in some special cases, ones that I haven't been able to reproduce, after lots of attempts.

Could someone with experience in implementing custom errors, please tell me if the refactoring that was done is 1:1 correct, or if I've missed something.

**Original ES5 Code**

```
function CustomError(errCode) {
    var temp = Error.apply(this, arguments);
    temp.name = this.name = 'CustomError';
    this.stack = temp.stack;
    this.code = errCode;
}

CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: CustomError,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
});

CustomError.prototype.toString = function () {
    console.log('errCode:', this.code);
};

CustomError.prototype.inspect = function () {
    return this.toString();
};
```

**Refactored ES6 Code:**

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    constructor(errCode) {
        super();
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, CustomError);
        this.code = errCode;
    }
}

CustomError.prototype.toString = function () {
    console.log('errCode:', this.code);
};

CustomError.prototype.inspect = function () {
    return this.toString();
};
```

Both examples are required to work the same under any Node.js 4.x and later, instantiated as:

```
const error = new CustomError(123);
console.log(error);
```

According to a bug report, sometimes such a type is supposedly created without the right `this` context, or more accurately, the error says: `can't use 'code' of undefined` that's inside `toString`.

**UPDATE**

After looking at this article: [Custom JavaScript Errors in ES6](https://medium.com/@xjamundx/custom-javascript-errors-in-es6-aa891b173f87#dc02), and its example:

```
class GoodError extends Error {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args)
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, GoodError)
    }
}
```

it seems that passing in the arguments like that is what I am missing. But how can I update my `CustomError` class correctly to do the same, considering that:

- Syntax `...args` doesn't work in Node.js 4.x, so I cannot use it
- I need to combine it with the existing custruction parameters, such as `errCode`

Comment: One thing to notice is `super()` should be `super(arguments)`.

Comment: @destoryer Shouldn't it be `super(...arguments)`?

Comment: @PeterMader Yes, thanks.

Comment: I can't think of anything you could do that would prevent the `this` context from being passed correctly.

Comment: At the top 2 comments above. Guys, then how come I cannot reproduce the problem? Why does it always work for me? That's what really confusing.

Comment: @vitaly-t I don't think the comments were intended to address the problem, they're just general comments about the right way to create a subclass.

Comment: @PeterMader why is it `super(...arguments)` and not `super(arguments)`? b.t.w., I cannot use the former, that syntax isn't supported in Node.js 4.x

Comment: `Error.apply(this, arguments)` seems wrong. The `Error` constructor expects the parameters to be `([message[, fileName[, lineNumber]]])`, you're passing the error code as the `message` argument.

Comment: Why are you using the class syntax and prototype syntax? Why not use one?

Comment: @evolutionxbox valid notice, but perhaps not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Barmar you are talking about the original ES5 code - one that's always worked correctly :) That is not the implementation with the problem, it is the ES6 version.

Comment: In fact, calling `super()` with no arguments seems like it should *fix* that bug.

Comment: @vitaly-t hence my comment not being an answer =)

Comment: I have added an update to my question. Can anybody answer with a usable example of a properly refactored class, please, one that would work with existing construction parameters and could run under Node.js 4.x?

Comment: @vitaly-t node.js 4.x support it with the --harmony flag.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli thank you, I know, still can't use it, it is for a public library, would be too error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is equivalent to your ES5 code

```
class CustomError extends Error {

    constructor( errCode ){
        super(...arguments);
        this.name = "CustomError";
        this.code = errCode;
    }

    toString(){
        console.log('errCode:', this.code);
    }

    inspect(){
        return this.toString();
    }

}
```

You can replace `super(...arguments)` with

```
super();
Error.apply(this, arguments);
```

Comment: Thank you! This will take me a few days to get feedback from the library's users to find out whether or not this helped with the problem. But for the moment it seems like the best I can try so far.

Comment: Why did you skip this line though? - `Error.captureStackTrace(this, CustomError)`. I thought it was essential for capturing the stack trace.

Comment: It was not in the ES5 code, and I believe it's redundant. `super(...arguments)`, or generally `new Error()` sets the `.stack` property.

Comment: Not according to this: https://medium.com/@xjamundx/custom-javascript-errors-in-es6-aa891b173f87 or is this guy wrong?

Comment: After all the feedback, and lots of experimenting I gave up, and reverted everything back to the ES5 syntax: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/361. I still have no idea what was wrong, and applying the code from this answer didn't help, sadly.